# Forking in $Q_p$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

I understand that the p-adic field with valuation has NTP2 and so forking=dividing. Does anyone have any explicit examples or a way of characterizing non-forking types and formulas in the theory of $Q_p$ (with valuation)?